# How does Firebase's profileURL work?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Super ignorant question but here goes it :

So I'm looking to make a super simple app where people have profiles, and other people can view those profiles. I'm a little confused as to how Firebase's built in user.profileURL works?

I've sort of avoided working with Images with Firebase thus far (and I really have barely worked with uploading/downloading images at all w/ Swift  in my learning so far), but from what I've heard you're obviously not storing full images up to firebase because of storage issues.

It takes a NSURL, so are you just good to go regardless of user count? And where exactly is this stored, seeing as it's not going to be in your actual database?

Comment: check out firebase auth docs to learn about it

Comment: are you talking about user authTokens or something else...can you be a little more specific with what help you need?

Comment: Firebase can definitely handle anything from thumbnails to full images. If you have a very small image you can store that right within Firebase (not recommended but it's doable). If you need to store larger images, that's what [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) is for. In what context are you referring to user.profileURL. Is that something you want to build?